# rss feed reader script

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss-reader

Is there any rss reader script that will combine multiple feeds and will keep updating the feed in
every 5 min or less??
i need this script for my website
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex18/gajaxrssdisplayer.htm

```
{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
}
```

which includes the above google api and so it takes 1hr to update the feed

help would be appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can load multiple feeds like that

```
function someHandler(){
// some init code before this
    var feed1 = new google.feeds.Feed("http://example.com/feed1");
    var feed2 = new google.feeds.Feed("http://example.com/feed2");
// some load/after process after this
}
```

And if you want to update every 5 seconds you can use

```
var updateInterval = window.setInterval(someHandler, 5000);
```